# Maven cucumber test code in one module and test execution in another

Tags: maven, cucumber

I want to keep my cucumber tests (.feature files) in a separate jar project (for packing only as test-jar) and declare this jar as a dependency in another project to be run there.

**A** is the test jar project (generating **A-0.1-tests.jar**)
**B** is the project that declares **A** as a test dependency

Should this work? It doesn't run any tests for my. Simply ignores the **test** goal.

Here is a pom snippet:

**A** *creates* the jar like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>tests</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**B** *calls* this jar like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

I am missing something... Anyone?

Comment: First question why would you like to separate your unit test from your module where the associated production live? Do you have particular reason for doing so?

Comment: I've updated my question. I refer to cucumber tests.

Comment: I have a similar situation: I actually *really need* the cucumber tests to be in another module - they are a compatibility test-suite for a command protocol, and *my* demo implementation won't be the only one. The invocation of the tests, with fixtures etc, must live in a third module relating to a particular implementation. Did you find a way to run the test-jar, please?

Answer (score -1):

Your tests don't exist in your main module, so maven won't run them, even if there is a dependency on the tests (which means that your main code needs the tests in order to execute, which is wrong anyway).

You don't need to do that at all. If you follow the standard code structures documented in maven you'll find everything much easier -- including creating your test-code jar. You should have your main and test code in a single module -- this works for everyone else in the entire industry, you don't need to invent anything new yourself, if you just go with it you'll be ok.

You can use the mvn jar plugin `mvn jar:test-jar` to create a jar with your tests in it, separate from the other classes in your module, without having the tests in a separate module. [Here is a document describing this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html)

Comment: I've updated my question. I refer to cucumber tests.

Comment: -1, sorry, this feels like a frame-challenge answer - Eldad wants the tests to be run from another module, and this answer doesn't say how to do it. I have a similar situation: a cucumber compatibility test-suite, designed to validate implementations of a protocol, for several implementations of that protocol. If you added how to do that, it would be a useful answer.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The OP doesn't mention modules, only jar files, and this answers that question by mentioning the mvn jar command.